# Will "-x objective-c++" compiler flag influences the build result of pure c++ source files with clang++?

Tags: c++, ios, clang++, objective-c++

Assums that all .cpp files are pure c++ source files(without any objective-c code), then will `a.out` be different with `b.out` ? and why ?

```
clang++ *.cpp -o a.out 
clang++ -x objective-c++ *.cpp -o b.out
```

Comment: Did you try `diff a.out b.out`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, but just a hello-world demo, there is a little bit difference while their file size is same.